# Google Calendar API: how to add freebusy permission to user's calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace, service-accounts

In my web app I need to add freebusy read permission for my service account to the primary calendar of gmail addresses provided by users.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account)

1. From your domain’s Admin console, go to Main menu menu > Security > Access and data control > API controls.
2. In the Domain wide delegation pane, select Manage Domain Wide Delegation.
3. Click Add new.
4. In the Client ID field, enter the client ID obtained from the service account creation steps above.
5. In the OAuth Scopes field, enter a comma-delimited list of the scopes required for your application. Use the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar for full access to the Google Calendar API.
6. Click Authorize.

Comment: Sorry, I guess it is my poor English and lack of knowledge about the subject; I meant how do I get the end user's consent and get the permission created on behalf of them in the first place.

Comment: You are using a service account, you don't.  Service accounts are pre authorized in the case of google calendar though google workspace.   If you want to request consent of a user then you should be using Oauth2 not a service account.

Comment: I must've misunderstood the concepts. In that case, I see only two ways:
1. Ask the user authorization for full access, and then add the permission, which is too bad.
2. Ask them to manually add the permission.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: You can't ask them to manually add permission to a service account with the google calendar API its not allowed.    Use oauth2 and authorize the user

Comment: What if I use the project owner's gmail instead? Using oauth2 gives me an access token which expires in an hour; I need the permission for as long as the user decides to revoke it.

Comment: Thats why you use a refresh token to get a new access token.    Project owner of the project on google developer console has nothing to do with the access granted to a users calendar account.   [Watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w)

Comment: Now I get it, thank you. I'm going to accept your answer because surely it answers the wrong question I asked.